# Supporting optional parameters in an Informatica Integration Assignment Step

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

My current implementation request body does not support optional attributes:

[image]

If say `phoneHome` is `null`, then the wanted behaviour is for the `JSON` to not include the attribute at all, e.g. what I want is :

```
{ 
    "phoneWork": "value here",
    "phoneMobile": "value here",
    "email": "value here"
}
```

Not:

```
{ 
    "phoneHome": "",
    "phoneWork": "value here",
    "phoneMobile": "value here",
    "email": "value here"
}
```

I have tried looping through all elements in the event and returning only the values that are not null, but I am not able to get it working.
Pseudocode:

```
for $i in
(
    $input.event_input[1]/xxx_Contact_Work_PHONE__c,
    $input.event_input[1]/xxx_Contact_Home_PHONE__c,
    $input.event_input[1]/xxx_Contact_Mobile_PHONE__c,
    $input.event_input[1]/xxx_Contact_Contact_EMAIL1__c 
)
return if ($i = "null")
then do nothing
else add the attribute to a JSON
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula, when given an XML as input, will remove all elements with no data.

**Example**

With the following input

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from></from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  <element></element>
</note>
```

it produces the following output

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

This is the solution I found:

```
<!--Initialize variable with the input XML-->
let $sources:=$input.XML_input
<!--Initialize variable with the distinct nodes using X-PATH-->
let $labels:=fn:distinct-values($sources/*/fn:node-name(.))
return
for $s in $sources
    return 
    <source>
    {
    for $l in $labels
        <!--Return element if value exists, nothing if no value-->
        return 
        if (fn:exists($s/*[fn:node-name()=$l]/text()))
        then ($s/*[fn:node-name()=$l])
        else ""
    }
    </source>
```